# Arango db importer (arangodbimp) connected but permission denied on file collection import

Tags: arangodb

I want to use the importer binary, but it throws "***Permission denied***" whatever options I choose.

[image]

I have created the database **test**, the user **test** and the collection **persons** through the ArangoDB Web interface.

I tried

- Using the root
- "--create-collection true" before creating the collection
- without sudo & with sudo

I can import the collection through the Web Interface and it imports just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand if it is a password issue can you please try the following workaround.

`sudo -S <<< "your_password" your_command`

The reasoning is that arangoimp is looking for the password once again and is taking newline as password. Hence the error permission denied.
Here the option `-S <<<` takes the password and substitutes it every time for the incoming password requests.

However, this is just a *workaround* if it works and not an ultimate solution since it's not safe to have passwords visible in your command history.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I still get the same message. Tried with the root user also, same message, but as for the password you were right it no longer asks for it.

Comment: @JannesBotis Did you manage to solve this error? Do you still get this issue while importing?

Comment: No, I could not get this to work. Just tried it again and got the same error.  I can only import through the web interface.